# Whats in an icloud backup

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I have an old icloud backup and I'd like to see whats in it. I'm worried that if I backup my current phone to icloud - restore it from the old backup (to see what it contains) - and then finally restore it from the current backup - maybe I will lose something. Is everything on my phone backed up (assuming I have all the toggles on)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you have made a backup of the data you want to keep via iTunes or iCloud it is safe to restore your phone from an old backup and later restore it to its present state from the backup you had made.
I would suggest using iTunes just because it seems more convenient to me and so as to you would feel safer about your data- an iTunes backup holds all the information necessary to restore your phone to its state at a set point in time.

Comment: So an exact copy - down to my recent call list etc? Or just a copy of apps / music and data held for those apps etc?

Comment: Yes, an exact copy.

Comment: You could make the backup encrypted in order to save some of the private data(Activity, Health and Keychain).